# Format slf4j.simpleLogger relative time (incl. milliseconds) since maven start

Tags: java, maven, gitlab-ci, slf4j

Using `MAVEN_OPTS=-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true` makes it print out the milliseconds since maven command started in front of every line of output. So far, so good.

Now i would like to add a `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.dateTimeFormat` to the MAVEN_OPTS so that it also displays minutes, seconds, and milliseconds since the job started, because seeing something like `151875 [INFO]` in a CI job log is not very intuitive and can be misleading – `2m31s875ms` or `2:31.875` is much more readable and to the point.

I could live with just `151.875` for starters, but i'm struggling to even achieve that. I tried `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.dateTimeFormat=ss.SSS` but as soon as i add that to MAVEN_OPTS it starts to print out *absolute* time again (in other words, it tells the clock) rather than *relative* time since maven started.